# template in templated function not parsed as template but as comparison

Tags: c++, parsing, templates

I have this trivial function templated on `Scalar` type which in turn uses Eigen templates.

```
#include<Eigen/Core>

template<typename Scalar>
void somefunc(){
    Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,9,1> v;
    v.segment<3>(3).setZero();
}
```

When compiling with `g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 ex.cc`, I get

```
a.cc: In function ‘void somefunc()’:
a.cc:6:18: error: request for member ‘setZero’ in ‘3’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  v.segment<3>(3).setZero();
                  ^~~~~~~
```

meaning the code was parsed as `v.segment` `[smaller-than]` `3` `[greater-than]` `(3).setZero()` and not as template argument. I tried adding `typename` in front of `Eigen::Matrix` but it does not change anything.

What's wrong? I must be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: You use the wrong keyword, in the wrong place: `v.template segment<3>(3).setZero();`

Comment: Great, I knew it was supposed to go somewhere. Thanks for teaching me! :)